# How do I random my quiz in database without duplicate

Tags: java, android, sqlite

This is my Activity where the question is executed

I don't know where I should code and what code should i put for it to random a question without any duplicate question(I believe its qid).

```
package com.example.testing;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class QuestionActivity extends Activity{

    List<Question> quesList;
    int score = 0;
    int qid = 0;
    int lives = 5;




    Question currentQ;
    TextView txtQuestion, times, scored, livess;
    Button button1, button2, button3;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        QuizHelper db = new QuizHelper(this);  // my question bank class
        quesList = db.getAllQuestions();  // this will fetch all quetonall questions
        currentQ = quesList.get(qid); // the current question
        txtQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtQuestion);
        // the textview in which the question will be displayed
        // the three buttons,
        // the idea is to set the text of three buttons with the options from question bank
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

        livess = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.livess);
        // the textview in which  will be displayed
        scored = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
        // the timer
        times = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timers);
        // method which will set the things up for our game
        setQuestionView();
        times.setText("00:02:00");
        // A timer of 60 seconds to play for, with an interval of 1 second (1000 milliseconds)
        CounterClass timer = new CounterClass(60000, 1000);
        timer.start();
        // button click listeners
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // passing the button text to other method
                // to check whether the anser is correct or not
                // same for all three buttons
                getAnswer(button1.getText().toString());
            }
        });
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getAnswer(button2.getText().toString());
            }
        });
        button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getAnswer(button3.getText().toString());
            }
        });
    }
    public void getAnswer(String AnswerString) {
        if (currentQ.getANSWER().equals(AnswerString)) {
            // if conditions matches increase the int (score) by 1
            // and set the text of the score view
            score++;
            scored.setText("Score : " + score);




        } else if(lives > 1){
            lives--;
            livess.setText("Lives: " + lives);

        }
        else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(QuestionActivity.this,
                    ResultActivity.class);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putInt("score", score); // Your score
            intent.putExtras(b); // Put your score to your next
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();


        }

        {


        }
        if (qid < 20) {
            // if questions are not over then do this
            currentQ = quesList.get(qid);
            setQuestionView();
        } else {
            // if over do this
            Intent intent = new Intent(QuestionActivity.this,
                    ResultActivity.class);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putInt("score", score); // Your score
            intent.putExtras(b); // Put your score to your next
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public class CounterClass extends CountDownTimer {
        public CounterClass(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            times.setText("Time is up");
        }
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            long millis = millisUntilFinished;
            String hms = String.format(
                    "%02d:%02d:%02d",
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)
                            - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
                            .toHours(millis)),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis)
                            - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
                            .toMinutes(millis)));
            System.out.println(hms);
            times.setText(hms);
        }
    }
    private void setQuestionView() {
        // the method which will put all things together
        txtQuestion.setText(currentQ.getQUESTION());
        button1.setText(currentQ.getOPTA());
        button2.setText(currentQ.getOPTB());
        button3.setText(currentQ.getOPTC());
        qid++;
    }
}
```

and this is the database of my question and answer I'm using sqlite i dont know where should I code to random the question without duplicate.

```
package com.example.testing;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
public class QuizHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mathsone";
    // tasks table name
    private static final String TABLE_QUEST = "quest";
    // tasks Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "qid";
    private static final String KEY_QUES = "question";
    private static final String KEY_ANSWER = "answer"; // correct option
    private static final String KEY_OPTA = "opta"; // option a
    private static final String KEY_OPTB = "optb"; // option b
    private static final String KEY_OPTC = "optc"; // option c
    private SQLiteDatabase dbase;
    public QuizHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        dbase = db;
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST + " ( "
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_QUES
                + " TEXT, " + KEY_ANSWER + " TEXT, " + KEY_OPTA + " TEXT, "
                + KEY_OPTB + " TEXT, " + KEY_OPTC + " TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(sql);
        addQuestion();
        // db.close();
    }
    private void addQuestion() {
        Question q1 = new Question("5+2 = ?", "7", "8", "6", "7");
        this.addQuestion(q1);
        Question q2 = new Question("2+18 = ?", "18", "19", "20", "20");
        this.addQuestion(q2);
        Question q3 = new Question("10-3 = ?", "6", "7", "8", "7");
        this.addQuestion(q3);
        Question q4 = new Question("5+7 = ?", "12", "13", "14", "12");
        this.addQuestion(q4);
        Question q5 = new Question("3-1 = ?", "1", "3", "2", "2");
        this.addQuestion(q5);
        Question q6 = new Question("0+1 = ?", "1", "0", "10", "1");
        this.addQuestion(q6);
        Question q7 = new Question("9-9 = ?", "0", "9", "1", "0");
        this.addQuestion(q7);
        Question q8 = new Question("3+6 = ?", "8", "7", "9", "9");
        this.addQuestion(q8);
        Question q9 = new Question("1+5 = ?", "6", "7", "5", "6");
        this.addQuestion(q9);
        Question q10 = new Question("7-5 = ?", "3", "2", "6", "2");
        this.addQuestion(q10);
        Question q11 = new Question("7-2 = ?", "7", "6", "5", "5");
        this.addQuestion(q11);
        Question q12 = new Question("3+5 = ?", "8", "7", "5", "8");
        this.addQuestion(q12);
        Question q13 = new Question("0+6 = ?", "7", "6", "5", "6");
        this.addQuestion(q13);
        Question q14 = new Question("12-10 = ?", "1", "2", "3", "2");
        this.addQuestion(q14);
        Question q15 = new Question("12+2 = ?", "14", "15", "16", "14");
        this.addQuestion(q15);
        Question q16 = new Question("2-1 = ?", "2", "1", "0", "1");
        this.addQuestion(q16);
        Question q17 = new Question("6-6 = ?", "6", "12", "0", "0");
        this.addQuestion(q17);
        Question q18 = new Question("5-1 = ?", "4", "3", "2", "4");
        this.addQuestion(q18);
        Question q19 = new Question("4+2 = ?", "6", "7", "5", "6");
        this.addQuestion(q19);
        Question q20 = new Question("5+1 = ?", "6", "7", "5", "6");
        this.addQuestion(q20);
        Question q21 = new Question("5-4 = ?", "5", "4", "1", "1");
        this.addQuestion(q21);
        // END
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldV, int newV) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST);
        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }
    // Adding new question
    public void addQuestion(Question quest) {
        // SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_QUES, quest.getQUESTION());
        values.put(KEY_ANSWER, quest.getANSWER());
        values.put(KEY_OPTA, quest.getOPTA());
        values.put(KEY_OPTB, quest.getOPTB());
        values.put(KEY_OPTC, quest.getOPTC());
        // Inserting Row
        dbase.insert(TABLE_QUEST, null, values);
    }
    public List<Question> getAllQuestions() {
        List<Question> quesList = new ArrayList<Question>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST;
        dbase = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = dbase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Question quest = new Question();
                quest.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
                quest.setQUESTION(cursor.getString(1));
                quest.setANSWER(cursor.getString(2));
                quest.setOPTA(cursor.getString(3));
                quest.setOPTB(cursor.getString(4));
                quest.setOPTC(cursor.getString(5));
                quesList.add(quest);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        // return quest list
        return quesList;
    }
}
```

Comment: `SELECT ... ORDER BY SomeField RANDOM`

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Question> quesList;  //This is a array of question

quesList = db.getAllQuestions();  // this will fetch all quetonall questions from database

currentQ = quesList.get(qid);    // this is the current question at present its at 0th position(i.e first question)
```

And your displaying questions on textview in this method

```
private void setQuestionView() { 
       // the method which will put all things together 
       txtQuestion.setText(currentQ.getQUESTION());
       button1.setText(currentQ.getOPTA());
       button2.setText(currentQ.getOPTB());
       button3.setText(currentQ.getOPTC());
       qid++;
}
```

And if you need to display random questions,

```
quesList = db.getAllQuestions();   //array of questions

Random random = new Random();    // to get random array

currentQ = random.nextInt(quesList.size());   //assign random question to current question.
```

displaying on textview will be handled by setQuestionView() method

Comment: where should I input the code 
quesList = db.getAllQuestions();   //array of questions

Random random = new Random();    // to get random array

currentQ = random.nextInt(quesList.length);   //assign random question to current question.

Comment: Inside onCreate() method. Track "quesList" .

Comment: I'm sorry, as quesList is an array, it should be "quesList.size()"

Comment: quesList.length

Error:(42, 43) error: cannot find symbol variable length

Comment: i change it to (quesList.size) insted of (quesList.size()) because puting () gives me more error

but the problem is still the size when i declaire (quesList.size)

Error:(42, 34) error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to Question

Comment: currentQ = quesList.get( random.nextInt(quesList.size()));

Comment: currentQ = quesList.get( random.nextInt(quesList.size())); works but it didnt random the question and crash, so what I did i remove the currentQ = quesList.get(qid);

so my code is

 List<Question>quesList;
        quesList = db.getAllQuestions();  // this will fetch all quetonall questions
        Random random = new Random();
        currentQ = quesList.get(random.nextInt(quesList.size()));
        currentQ = quesList.get(qid); // the current question
        txtQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtQuestion);

It did random the question but, the application crash,

Comment: Allright i already manage to make i work but it keep numbers duplicate

Answer (score 0):

- To keep track of used questions create `ArrayList<Integer> questionsDone`.
- To generate random question, create object of `java.util.Random` class and get random integer upto the number of questions in database

  `int totalQuestions = cursor.getCount();` and get new question id using
  `int questionId = random.nextInt(totalQuestions);`
- Before going to display it to user, check if it contains in `questionsDone` array. If contains then generate another question as it is duplicate question.